# Insignificant VAR coefficients

Tags: time-series, econometrics, vector-autoregression

I am not quite familiar with vector autoregression (VAR).

I am thinking of using VAR/IRF (impulse response functions) to illustrate the relations between some time series variables.

However, most of the coefficients are not significant. One note I found says it is rare to report the coefficients. I am kind of confused here.

To my purpose, is it a big problem if the coefficients are not significant? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that your model doesn't describe the real process in a good way, maybe that is worth to report, if you can't change any of the variables? It's usually hard to say something certain about the relationship between variables from the coefficients non-structural VAR models, especially if many lags are included and they have different signs and size.